# How to ref a value in a cell in range reference

Tags: excel, vba

This is for VBA in excel. I know we define a range like this Range("B5"). However, I need users to input a letter to indicate the column and the starting row in his/her case. So, it is like you put B into B1, and 5 into B2. I cannot get Range(B1, B2) to work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `Range(Cells(Row, Column), Cells(Row, Column))`. It would help if your example actually tied out to your example. You stated `B5` as an input and then didn't use that in your example

Comment: How will users actually be inputting the starting point? `InputBox`? Or will they actually be keying in the column & row into cells on the worksheet?

Comment: I see. My fault. I just used B5 as an example as how to express a cell location. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: No worries @Kele. I would recommend taking the input with a input box and restrict the input to a range. I.E. have users select the cell in question rather type it out somewhere

Comment: urdearboy, they will type in on the worksheet. Thank you!

Comment: Adding to @urdearboy's suggestion: if you use the [`Application.InputBox` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) instead of just the basic [`InputBox` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function), you get an extra parameter, `Type` - if you set this to `8` then it will give you a Range Picker, and also return a Range: `Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", Type:=8)`  Doesn't apply to this question, but hopefully prevents confusion if people read the comments!

Answer (score 0):

Use Cells(<row>, <column>) instead.

```
' equivalent of cells(5, "B") or range("B5")
i = cells(range("B2").value, range("B1").value).value

'alternate for range("B5") through string concatenation
i = range(range("B1").value & range("B2").value).value

'one more
i = intersect(rows(range("B2").value), columns(range("B1").value)).value
```

Comment: when B1 is a B, letter, the .value mismatch the type.

Comment: Change `.Value` to `.Text`, or just leave this out I.E. switch to `i = Cells(Range("B2"), Range("B1"))`

Comment: They all work. I put .Value in to make a point. It's the default property so omitting it only returns it anyways.

Comment: @KeleDing, *B* in a cell is the cell's value.

Comment: @user11060139 thank you very much. the .text way worked out, not without it.

Comment: @KeleDing, then you have other problems. `?range("B1").value = range("B1").text` in the Immediate window returns True. When *B* is in range("B1") with basic default formatting, there is no difference between .Value and .Text. (or .Value2 for that matter)

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

   Dim Column As Long, Row As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Check if both fields (B1 & C1) are not empty
        If .Range("B1").Value <> "" And .Range("C1").Value <> "" Then
            'Convert letter to number
            Column = .Range(.Range("B1").Value & 1).Column 'or you can directly use Column = .Range("B1").Value and change Column variable from Long to String
            Row = .Range("C1").Value
            'Select the cell you refer to
            .Cells(Row, Column).Select
        Else: MsgBox "Please fill both B1 & C1 fields."
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You *can* use `Cells` with a Letters for columns (i.e. `.Cells(2, "C").Select` is the same as `.Cells(2, 3).Select`), so converting the letter to a number for Column is not necessary - and not converting means that if the user types "3" instead of "C" you would be able parse it without an error.

Comment: @Chronocidal i have edit the answer providing both answers.

Comment: @Chronocidal if you use directly cell value you have to change column variable type from long to string.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ exacly the same thing with this answer. Someone devote